# NodeJS monitor for Google Forms submissions

Tags: node.js, rest, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-forms

I am trying to set up a NodeJS application that monitors for new responses on a Google Form so that they can be displayed on a dashboard.

My original idea was to use the responses spreadsheet, but I can't find a way to convert it into readable JSON. The next problem is identifying which responses are new. The storage of the app is very very limited and having a copy of the spreadsheet is out of the question. What I wanted to is just ping the table every 1 hour and if there's a new response, run some code to print the data.

I am open to any ideas or suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can maintain a counter in the app, or in a shared file/database. The counter will point to number of rows seen in the spreadsheet. Next time you query the spreadsheet, you'd know rows after counter are new.

As per extracting the data, if you have the sheet as a file, you can use some package like [xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) to parse the sheet into JSON. If not, then you can fetch the spreadsheet from Google APIs in JSON format.